# Hyperledger Fabric - Channel hasn't started yet

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

After an unfortunate docker outage, one of our test channels has stopped working properly. This is the output of a previously working “peer chaincode invoke” command:

```
Error: error sending transaction for invoke: got unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- will not enqueue, consenter for this channel hasn't started yet - proposal response: version:1 response:<status:200 payload:"be85bda14845a33cd07db9825d2e473dc65902e6986fdfccea30d8c32385f758" > payload:"\n \364\242+\t\222\216\361\020\024}d7\203\277WY04\233\225vA\376u\330r\2045\312\206\304\333\022\211\001\n3\022\024\n\004lscc\022\014\n\n\n\004strs\022\002\010\004\022\033\n\004strs\022\023\032\021\n\tkeepalive\032\004ping\032E\010\310\001\032@be85bda14845a33cd07db9825d2e473dc65902e6986fdfccea30d8c32385f758\"\013\022\004strs\032\0031.0" endorsement:<endorser:"\n\013BackboneMSP\022\203\007-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- etc. more output removed from here
```

I find this in the orderer's log:

```
2019-07-29 14:46:50.930 UTC [orderer/consensus/kafka] try -> DEBU 3c10 [channel: steel] Connecting to the Kafka cluster
2019-07-29 14:46:50.931 UTC [orderer/consensus/kafka] try -> DEBU 3c11 [channel: steel] Need to retry because process failed = kafka server: The requested offset is outside the range of offsets maintained by the server for the given topic/partition.
2019-07-29 14:46:56.967 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 3c12 Error reading from 10.0.0.4:32800: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-07-29 14:46:56.967 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 3c13 Closing Deliver stream
2019-07-29 14:46:56.972 UTC [orderer/common/server] Deliver -> DEBU 3c14 Starting new Deliver handler
2019-07-29 14:46:56.972 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 3c15 Starting new deliver loop for 10.0.0.4:32802
2019-07-29 14:46:56.973 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 3c16 Attempting to read seek info message from 10.0.0.4:32802
2019-07-29 14:46:56.973 UTC [common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 3c17 [channel: steel] Rejecting deliver request for 10.0.0.4:32802 because of consenter error
2019-07-29 14:46:56.973 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 3c18 Waiting for new SeekInfo from 10.0.0.4:32802
2019-07-29 14:46:56.973 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 3c19 Attempting to read seek info message from 10.0.0.4:32802
2019-07-29 14:46:56.995 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 3c1a Error reading from 10.0.0.23:49844: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-07-29 14:46:56.995 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 3c1b Closing Deliver stream
```

And this is from the endorser peer’s log:

```
2019-07-29 15:14:17.829 UTC [ConnProducer] DisableEndpoint -> WARN 3d6 Only 1 endpoint remained, will not black-list it
2019-07-29 15:14:17.834 UTC [blocksProvider] DeliverBlocks -> WARN 3d7 [steel] Got error &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
2019-07-29 15:14:27.839 UTC [blocksProvider] DeliverBlocks -> WARN 3d8 [steel] Got error &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
```

I use these docker images:

- hyperledger/fabric-kafka:0.4.10
- hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.2.0
- hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.2.0

Based on the above, I assume that the consistency between the orderer and the corresponding kafka topic is broken. It also doesn't help if I redirect requests to another orderer or force to change the kafka topic leader. Is it correct that if KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS=-1 had been set, this error would probably have been prevented?

After reviewing the archives, I found that it is not possible to fix this error. As I see it, I can't shutdown only one channel, and I even have to stop all the peers subscribed to the channel if I don't want continuous error messages in the orderer logs. What is the best practice in cases like mine?

Regards;
Sandor

Comment: Did you try setting `unclean.leader.election.enable` to `true` in your broker config(s)?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Everything is the same.

Comment: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-11334 - Thanks Gari

Answer (score 0):

> consenter error

---

> which means before connection made b/w kafka & orderer you are trying
>   to do some operations.

```
Which means there is an error present in between kafka and orderer
```

Note: Probably you might have set up a connection which is not stable 
      Try to check the logs of orderer it should have a message posted 
      successfully. 
      whenever Kafka, orderer try to connect, orderer will post a message if it 
      successfully posted to a topic which means you have configured correctly

Make sure connection b/w kafka and orderer are configured correctly

```
2019-07-29 14:46:50.931 UTC [orderer/consensus/kafka] try -> DEBU 3c11 [channel: steel] Need to retry because process failed = kafka server: The requested offset is outside the range of offsets maintained by the server for the given topic/partition.
```

By above clue, it is complete with Kafka nothing todo with the orderer
try check [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/docker-compose-kafka.yaml)

Comment: Communication between Kafka brokers and Orderers is fine, the other channels work properly.

Comment: Hey, then check configtx.yaml of your configuration values. I guess you are violating something. Check MaxMessageCount, AbsoluteMaxBytes, PreferredMaxBytes